# Error using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to concatenate results for one column into a text string and came across the `FOR XML PATH`. I tried to use it but kept getting

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

or

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'XML'

Here is my code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   i1.CompanyID,
   i1.Company,
   i1.IncidentID,
   i1.Description,
   i1.CreatedDate,
   i1.AssignedTo,
   i1.Priority,
   i1.StatusID,
   i1.Status,

   Notes = REPLACE( (SELECT Notes AS [data()] 
                     FROM tempdb.dbo.tempIncident i2 
                     WHERE i1.IncidentID = i2.IncidentID
                     ORDER BY i2.Notes
                     FOR XML PATH ('')), ' ', ',')
FROM 
   tempdb.dbo.tempIncident i1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an older version of `SQL Server` like SQL2000 where **XML Path is not supported**. If you look `PATH` is not marked as keyword in blue.

Take alook at this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) you will find a way to do string concatenation in SQL 2000.

Comment: yes, you are right it is sql 2000 but I just found out that the data is replicated on another sql 2005 server so I will try it there.

Comment: Your query worked fine for me. I am sure it will work fine for you also in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    i1.CompanyID,
    i1.Company,
    i1.IncidentID,
    i1.[Description],
    i1.CreatedDate,
    i1.AssignedTo,
    i1.[Priority],
    i1.StatusID,
    i1.[Status],
    STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + i2.Notes  [text()] 
            FROM tempdb.dbo.tempIncident i2 
            WHERE  i1.IncidentID = i2.IncidentID
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1, 2, '') AS [Notes]
FROM tempdb.dbo.tempIncident i1
GROUP BY i1.CompanyID,
        i1.Company,
        i1.IncidentID,
        i1.[Description],
        i1.CreatedDate,
        i1.AssignedTo,
        i1.[Priority],
        i1.StatusID,
        i1.[Status]
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I still got the same error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'."

Comment: Try taking out ORDER BY clause in your FOR XML Query, and what data type Notes column is ?

Comment: is there any configurations that need to be done to be able to use this function? if I remove the order by the error changes to "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'XML'."

Comment: Notes is nvarchar(4000)

Comment: post your latest query that you have built after seeing my suggested solution. Have you change `[data()]` to `[text()]` in your select statement and please use square brackets `[]` around column names that are sql server key words like in your case you have `Status`, `Description` columns

Comment: If you just simply copy paste the query as it is, does it throw any error?